# Is given statement decidable or undecidable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

A given non-terminal A in a given grammar CFG is ever used in the generation of word.-Decidable/undecidable?

---

My attempt:

It should be decidable problem, We can solve this problem using membership algorithm for context free grammar- I'm stuck here.

> Can you explain in brief way, please?

Comment: Is the question whether there is any derivation involving $A$, or whether there is a word that _needs_ $A$ for being derived?

Comment: Also, why do you want a _formal_ explanation? What does "formal" mean to you here?

Comment: Question is not clear, but it seems to me that "is any derivation involving $A$?". However, can you explain both situation, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the question is "is there any derivation involving $A$"?

First you need to know which nonterminals can unfold to any word at all. You can find this by fixpoint iteration: start with an empty set, and whenever there's a production $B::=s_1\cdots s_k$ where each $s_i$ is either a terminal or a nontermial you have already identified as fully-unfoldable, then $B$ is fully unfoldable too.

Once you know the fully-unfoldable terminals, check whether there's a way for $S$ to derive a string that involves $A$ using only the fully-unfoldable productions you found before. That is a simple graph reachability problem.

---

If, on the other hand, the question is, "is there any word that can be produced *with* $A$ but not *without* it?" then this question is undecidable, because subset-inclusion of context-free languages is undecidable.